# How do I check that there is no specific data in postman response?

Tags: javascript, testing, postman

I am sending a request that creates an issue in postman. I get a json data in response and I need to check that this data does not contain specified element. How do I do it in tests?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: What is the response body and what is the value that you don't want it to contain? Without that basic information, no one is going to be able to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm that a value is missing from the json response, you can use `pm.expect(jsonResponse.value).to.be.undefined`.

Here is the full example:

```
pm.test("valueThatShouldNotBePresent is missing from the json response", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.valueThatShouldNotBePresent).to.be.undefined;
});
```

Check out the [Test Script Examples](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

Also we can do the following:

```
  const jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.test('Key abc is absent', () => {
        pm.expect(jsonData).to.not.have.any.keys('abc')
    })
```